# Set an alias in csh taking parameters from commandline

Tags: unix, csh, tr

I am trying to create an alias in csh for converting word to uppercase.
I have made the following entry in my .cshrc file:

`alias upper "!$" | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]"`

However when I run `upper abc` i get the following error:

tr: extra operand `abc'

Try `tr --help' for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should work in csh aon adding to your .cshrc file:

`alias upper '\!*  | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]"'`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
alias upper \!:1  | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]"
```